# How to embed an office document in a Metro App?

Tags: windows-8, ms-office

Is it possible to embed an office document in a Metro app without having to parse it manually? 
I'm thinking about a preview or even a the possibility to make small changes to it. I'm not asking about starting it externally but using it directly in a Metro app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot embed directly into a Metro style app.  It may be possible to do something with the [Skydrive API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826521) and [embedding documents](http://www.excelmashup.com/), but more research would be required.  [Here is an example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Live-SDK-Windows-Developer-8ad35141) on using the Live SDK from a Metro style app.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use webview controller and open the document from Skydrive with it.

That way you can open the document as editable or just show it.